# Automatic date retrieval in SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

We are currently using a SQL query where we retrieve data of current date within specified time like in between below time-stamps"

```
to_date('2016-05-10 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
and 
to_date('2016-05-10 23:59:59','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'
```

Is there any way to get above mentioned dates and time automatically rather than changing it daily?

Comment: `where trunc(the_column) = trunc(sysdate)`? But beware: this will not make use of an index on `the_column`. If you need this, you need to create an index on `trunc(the_column)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SYSDATE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions179.htm) to get the current date, and [`TRUNC`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions209.htm) to remove the time portion of a date:

```
x >= TRUNC( SYSDATE ) AND x < TRUNC( SYSDATE + 1 )
```

---

This gets the same results as `TRUNC(x) = TRUNC(SYSDATE)` but will allow to use an index on `x`.

As *a_horse_with_no_name* commented, the second query would benefit from a function-based index on `TRUNC(x)`.